# show div based on user role in database php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

After searching and trying different methods on here without success I thought I would ask.

Something like this would be perfect but I dont know how to set it to check user roles

```
<?php
    if (roles->getUserRole(reports)) { echo "<li><a href='/page5'>Reports</a></li>"; }
?>
```

I am wanting to show/not show a menu item based on the user role in the database. I have it set in the databse up as

(Admin) Role - 1 or (SuperAdmin) Role 2

[image]

Here is the login.php

```
    <?php
session_start(); // Starting Session

    $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";

    }  else  {

        // Define $myusername and $mypassword
        $myusername=$_POST['username'];
        $mypassword=$_POST['password'];

    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_admin", "db-password");
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose

    $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
    $mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("db_database", $connection);

    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
    $query = mysql_query("select * from members where password='$mypassword' AND username='$myusername'", $connection);
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
    $_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername; // Initializing Session
        header("location: dashboard.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page

    } else {

    $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
}
}
?>
```

The code at the top of dashboard.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

  } else {
header ("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

And the menu item I want to show/hide based on user role.

```
       <li>
          <a href="employees.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            Employees
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
          <li><a href="employees.php"><i class="fa fa-th-list nav-icon"></i> See All</a></li>  
            <li><a href="add-employee.php"><i class="fa fa-plus-square-o nav-icon"></i> Add</a></li>
            <li><a href="edit-employee.php"><i class="fa fa-edit nav-icon"></i> Edit</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

As a side note (because I know it will be mentioned) I know my code should be mysqli and I am going to switch my site to that when I get it all working. I am learning it right now.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should store more than the user login in your session :
If the authentification succeded, then create an unique token using something like

```
    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
        $query = mysql_query("select * from members where password='$mypassword' AND username='$myusername'", $connection);
        $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if ($rows == 1) {
            $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername; // Initializing Session
            $token = md5(uniqid());
            $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
            $query = mysql_query("update token from members where username='$myusername' set token = '$token'", $connection);
            header("location: dashboard.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
        } else {
    ...
    }
```

This token will be used to validate the authentification on every other pages of your website, without it you are only assuming that if there is a login_name inside your session, then authentification is correct.

This will work, of course, but that's not secure at all, if an user want to update his password, other computers already logged on the same account will never be disconnected.

Using a token, you will be able to reset it later on password change.

---

In other pages you can then use session username to get current token and current role.

```
// Check for a session
 if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']) && isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
     // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
                $query = mysql_query("select * from members where  username='".$_SESSION['login_user']."'", $connection);
                $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                if ($rows == 1) {
                    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query , MYSQL_BOTH);
                    if($row['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])
                    {
                        // Incorrect token, disconnect the user
                        unset($_SESSION['login_user']);
                        unset($_SESSION['token_user']);
                        // Make redirection and stuff
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // User still logged
                           $role = $row['role'];
                        // You can then use that variable later in page
                        // If $role == 1, Admin, show menu, prevent function access, ect
                    }
               }
}
```

Hope it help !

Comment: I am getting this error - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ',' or ')' in /Admin/dashboard.php on line 4

Comment: @WebbieWorks, I didn't tried the code directly as it was more like an example than a copy/paste solution, however there was some syntax error, edited and corrected !